# Showing that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} F_{\mu_n}(x) = F_\mu(x)$

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence

Suppose $(\mu_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of probability measures (on $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}$)) that I wish to show converges weakly to $\mu$. One way of doing is of course to show that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} F_{\mu_n}(x) = F_\mu(x)$, where $F$ denotes the distribution function) for every continuity point $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Say I have already proven that this is true for $x$ with either $F_\mu(x) \geq F_{\mu_n}(x)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ or $F_\mu(x) \leq F_{\mu_n}(x)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Can I use this to show this for an arbitray continuity point $x$? I was thinking of taking an arbitrary subsequence and showing that this sequence has a convergent subsequence - but I am not sure how to utilize what I have shown.

Comment: The answer seems to be no. For example, fix $m\in\mathbb{N}$ an conducer $\mu_n=\delta_{\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{n}}$ and $\mu=\delta_0$. We have that $\mu_n\Longrightarrow\nu:=\delta_{\frac{1}{m}}$, and $\lim_n F_{\mu_n}(x)=F_\nu(x)\leq F_\mu(x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might not be sufficient. Take a standard normal random variable $Z$, and for $n\geq 1$ define a sequence of random variables $Z_n:=Z+\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$, Clearly $Z_n \to Z$ in distribution. Now pick an $x\in \mathbb{R}$, note that for even $n$, $F_{Z_n}(x)=\mathbb{P}(Z+\frac{1}{n}\leq x)$ is strictly smaller than $F_{Z}(x)=\mathbb{P}(Z\leq x)$, and for odd $n$,$F_{Z_n}(x)=\mathbb{P}(Z-\frac{1}{n}\leq x)$ is strictly larger than $F_{Z}(x)=\mathbb{P}(Z\leq x)$. Therefore there is no $x$ satisfying your assumptions. Hope this clarifies your doubts.